# How can I open emails accounts related to domain in windows azure

Tags: azure, web

I have a website running on windows azure. I want to attach domain that I purchased and create emails accounts with this domain.
How can I do this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it about support for Azure's service, not programming as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Azure does not offer any email service.  Check with your domain registrar, they usually offer that kind of service.  You can also use Office 365, Google Apps for Business or domains.live.com.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a VM, that runs an email / mailbox server.  Then update your MX records for the domain to point to that email server.  Other than that Azure doesn't provide email services.  It is a pure hosting environment for you to host your IaaS, Paas, and other cloud services.  You can't think of it in that traditional web hoster sense where they do all the provisioning of your domain, and associated email, website, storage accounts.  With Azure it is all up to you in how you want services created and consumed.

-john